# How to unit test the JSON exception and hit/cover the catch block

Tags: java, json, exception, junit, code-coverage

Here is a snippet of the code I am trying to cover, specifically the catch block.

```
JSONObject bodyObject = new JSONObject();
String body = null;

try{
   body = bodyObject.put(DecisionTreeConstants.EDGE_ACCOUNT_STATUS, processStatusPretty).toString();
} catch (JSONException e) {
   LOGGER.debug(" ");
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to test exception is thrown or test the handling of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to have a testdouble for the LOGGER injected and then check that it is called with the expected blank string.